# MongoCursor<BsonDocument> converting to List is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
 MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection("TestCollection");
 MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = collection.FindAll();
 List<BsonDocument> list = cursor.toList();
```

This is very slow executing.
MongoCursor converting to a List is very slow, but if I use the following code:

```
MongoCollection<T> collection = db.GetCollection<T>("TestCollection");
MongoCursor<T> cursor = collection.findAll();
List<T> entities = cursor.toList();
```

The above code is much faster. Why is MongoCursor converting to a List so slow? I want to use BsonDocument. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you checked that on the same amount of data? also... What is T in that case?

Comment: Yes I'm sure same collection is used. T is entity of collection data.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the time differences I measured on a 6,000 documents collection were statistically insignificant. Are you sure you're measuring correctly? What does your test-setup look like? How big is the difference between the two? What does the class `T` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug with driver 1.8.0 ~ 1.8.2. We run into the same issue some days ago and reported in the MongoDb JIRA [CSHARP-822](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-822). Upgrade to 1.8.3+ is supposed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you. İ downloaded master branch on github and build. Tried again. But it's still slow. Only one count MongoCursor<BsonDocument> convert to List<BsonDocument> takes about 2000 milisecond.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's merged to the master brunch, to us 1.8.3 resolved the issue. Maybe you should try with 1.8.3.

Comment: My bad. Just had a look at the JIRA and it seems the had merged it to master branch already. So there might be other reasons. How big is your collection? I'm going to had a test locally.